# Identify objects for drag and drop swapping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, swap

I am working on a project where cameras can be dragged and dropped onto targets, which are basically grids of dropzones. When a camera is dragged onto a dropzone, it should swap with the current content of that dropzone such that, what was in the dropzones content should now be where the dragged camera was and what was where the dragged camera was is now in the content of the dropzone.
[image: Image of the project]

My idea is to do something along the lines of this:

```
const draggedItem = cameras[i];
const target = targets[i].dropozones[i].content;
const temp = draggedItem;
draggedItem = target;
target = temp;
```

In this example an item is dragged from the cameras to the dropzone of a target. I also want it to swap when a camera from a dropzone is dragged onto another dropzone. The problem I am having is how to identify the dragged item and droptarget. I have tried using a bunch of find(), includes() and indexOf() to find the indexes I need to do the swapping. However this seems overkill and did not work either.

I am using vuejs. The target and camera array are components from which I am passing the drag events to App.vue where the following 'data structure'(I am not sure what to call this) is under data().

```
cameras: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "CAM_1",
    },
  ],
  targets: [
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "TARGET_1",
      columns: 3,
      rows: 3,
      dropzones: [
        {
          zoneNum: 0,
          content: [
            {
            id: 4,
            name: "CAM_4",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 1,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 2,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 3,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 4,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 5,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 6,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 7,
          content: [],
        },
        {
          zoneNum: 8,
          content: [],
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

To sum up, I am looking for a method to get a certain camera, that is in the cameras-array or in a dropzone, so I can swap them. Through my research I have stumbled across DFS and BFS, but dont know if that is useful in this situation.
Really hoping someone could help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at drag/drop libraries such as https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable ?

Comment: I have tried using vue draggable, but I only found it helpful for sorting not swapping, so I went back to native drag-and-drop

Comment: I've not used it, but there is a plugin specifically for swapping items: https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#swap

Comment: Oh, I’ll try it out. Isn’t vue draggable based on sortable.js? So then the swap funktionality would be part of vue draggable as well

Comment: It should be compatible with SortableJS, not part of it, as it's a plugin to extend the functionality of SortableJS.